How add a custom html class to WooCommerce loop add to cart link?
We want to add a CSS class to some specific buttons, by adding to some existing PHP.
This is our existing PHP - which changes the button text.  [gleaned from elsewhere in StackOverFlow]
/**
 * @snippet       Read more > Out of stock @ WooCommerce Shop
 * @how-to        businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-customization
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli, Business Bloomer
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 5
 * @community     https://businessbloomer.com/club/
 * See: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-rename-read-more-out-of-stock-shop/
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
  
function bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text( $text ) {
   global $product;       
   if ( $product && ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {         /* original example was:    ! $product->is_in_stock()  */
      return 'Active';
   } 
   return $text;
}

This is the html, after running the above php.
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " style="">
       <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>
       <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</bdi></span> 
       <span class="subscription-details"> for 2 years</span><br>
       <a href=".../membership/arts-events-marketing-subscription-copy/" [split]
aria-describedby="woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link_describedby_2242" data-quantity="1" [split]
class="button product_type_subscription" data-product_id="2242" data-product_sku="" [split]
aria-label="Read more about “Arts Events Marketing Subscription”" [split]
rel="nofollow" data-success_message="" data-product_price="0.0" [split]
data-product_name="Arts Events Marketing Subscription" data-google_product_id="">Active</a> 
       <span id="woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link_describedby_2242" class="screen-reader-text"></span>
</p

How can we add the class "ActiveSubscription" to the A element
----- one day later ----
This is the new code - but there is disparity between the 2 halves of the code.  The 1st half selects 3 subscriptions - and thus changes the text.
The 2nd half only selects two of the (above) subscriptions.
nb - three active subscriptions are correctly? reported elsewhere (in MyAccount page).  Replacing the 'if' statement with the original corrects the problem, but why the disparity?
/
**
 * @snippet       Read more > Out of stock @ WooCommerce Shop
 * @how-to        businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-customization
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli, Business Bloomer
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 5
 * @community     https://businessbloomer.com/club/
 * See: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-rename-read-more-out-of-stock-shop/
 */
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );
  
function bbloomer_archive_custom_cart_button_text( $text ) {
   global $product;       
   if ( $product && ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {         /* original example was:    ! $product->is_in_stock()  */
      return 'Active';
   } 
   return $text;
}

/* Also add a class so that custom css can grey-out the button */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ) {
    // Check if the product is part of an active subscription for the current user
    // if ( wcs_user_has_subscription( get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id(), 'active' ) ) {     replaced by line below for (attempted) commonality with function above
    if ( $product && ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        $link = str_replace('class="button', 'class="button ActiveSubscription', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}


You can use woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter hook with PHP str_replace() to add an additional selector class to WooCommerce Loop add to cart button link.
It seems, that you are using WooCommerce Subscriptions, and that you want to add that selector class, when a product is part of an active subscription for the current user. In that case, you can use wcs_user_has_subscription() function in an IF statement.
Try the following:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ) {
    // Check if the product is part of an active subscription for the current user
    if ( wcs_user_has_subscription( get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id(), 'active' ) ) {
        $link = str_replace('class="button', 'class="button ActiveSubscription', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Addition for variable subscriptions
If the current user has an active subscription from a variable subscription product, try the following instead:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ) {
    // For variable subscriptions
    if ( $product->is_type('variable-subscription') ) {
        // Loop through the variation IDs
        foreach( $product->get_children() as $variation_id ) {
            // Check if a variation is part of an active subscription for the current user
            if ( wcs_user_has_subscription( get_current_user_id(), $variation_id, 'active' ) ) {
                $link = str_replace('class="button', 'class="button ActiveSubscription', $link);
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    // For simple subscriptions
    elseif ( $product->is_type('subscription') ) {
        // Check if the product is part of an active subscription for the current user
        if ( wcs_user_has_subscription( get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id(), 'active' ) ) {
            $link = str_replace('class="button', 'class="button ActiveSubscription', $link);
        }
    }
    return $link;
}

Untested, it could work.

Related: Detecting if the current user has an active subscription

thanks, it work, but strangely (in my test case) the original code selects three subscriptions, but your code only two.  I changed your 'if' statement to same as the original one ... but it still only selects two of the three.    I'll add the new completed code to the original question,

@user801347 Note that my current answer answers your initial question and works. Now, if you are using variable subscriptions, see my addition (untested code replacement that should handle active variation subscriptions).
